# IsUpdateable returns true for Admin profile, even though I removed edit access

Tags: security, field-level-security

I am running checks on fields in my Apex controller, to see if the logged in user has update access on a field before allowing an update. While logged in as Admin, when I check `IsUpdateable()` in my Apex controller, it returns true, even when I have explicitly removed `Edit` access to that field using field-level security.

Here's an isolated example that can be run in Developer Console:

```
System.debug(Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().get('phone').getDescribe().isUpdateable());
```

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but shouldn't this return false if I uncheck `Phone` edit access in Administrator profile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Administrators have the "Edit Read Only Fields" permission, so removing "Edit" from a field has no effect on fields administrators can view. They can still edit fields which could be edited as if they had Edit permission on the field. If you remove the Visible attribute as well, then isUpdatable() would be false (because they can no longer see the field at all).

Comment: Note also that this "Edit Read Only Fields" permission can't be unchecked for the standard System Admin. If you want an Admin profile that respects read-only fields (to me it's super-annoying that this permission makes read-only fields on **layouts** also editable) you'll have to clone the Admin and uncheck on the clone and assign that profile instead.